# Python: Convert dataframe with 1 column to specific ndarray

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a pandas dataframe with 1 column and n rows, for example:

```
                              0
0                03110311000311
1             18003130313000313
2             36003120312000312
3             54003110311000311
4             72003100310000310
...                         ...
[1400 rows x 1 columns]
```

I converted this dataframe to ndarray using **to_numpy()** function, but I got this ndarray:

[image]

I would like get an ndarray like this: `y={ndarray:(1400,)}`

How can do it? Thanks!

Comment: Use `df.squeeze().to_numpy()` or `df[0].to_numpy()` or `df.to_numpy().squeeze()`

Comment: Just slice the Array via arr[:,0].

Comment: df.to_numpy() or df.values

Comment: @Ch3steR so simple! thank you very much! Works fine! Can you explain the difference between `YY` ndarray and `y` ndarray?

Answer (score 0):

Just select the column first:

```
df['column_index'].to_numpy()
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(6))

df.to_numpy().shape            # (6,1)

df[0].to_numpy().shape       # (6,)
```